# Test a Flask API that uses sqlite database

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I am writing a test for a flask API where a user can create an account. After running the test(unittest) I keep getting this error. Is there a better way to test that API ie Which I can also use to test the GET,PUT and DELETE requests?

TypeError: self.assertEqual(result["id"], "4")
'method' object is not subscriptable

Here is my database setup:

```
    class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    public_id = db.Column(db.String(50), unique = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

The API I want to test:

```
@APP.route('/user', methods = ['POST'])
def create_user():

    data = request.get_json(force = True)
    hashedpassword = generate_password_hash(data['password'], method= 'sha256')
    new_user = User(public_id = str(uuid.uuid4), name = data['name'], password = hashedpassword, admin = False)

    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
```

My test:

```
class testMainmodule(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        APP.testing = True
        self.app = APP.test_client()
        self.data = {"admin": False,
                "id": "4",
                "name": "njati",
                "password": "sha256$xfIUTEIX$6973717971585c3b7ebb593876def4124ff3eb4f8e30c3b43e2c8af20fe64952",
                "public_id": "<function uuid4 at 0x7fb631f93d08>"}

    def post_create_user(self, data = {}):
        if not data:
            data = self.data
        result= self.app.post(path = "/user", data = json.dumps(self.data), content_type = "application/json")
        json_response = json.loads(result.get_data(as_text=True))
        return jsonify(json_response)

    def test_create_user(self):
        result = self.post_create_user

        self.assertEqual(result["id"], "4")
        self.assertEqual(result["public_id"], "<function uuid4 at 0x7fb631f93d08>")
        self.assertTrue(result["admin"], False)
        self.assertEqual(result["name"], "njati")
        self.assertEqual(result["password"], "sha256$xfIUTEIX$6973717971585c3b7ebb593876def4124ff3eb4f8e30c3b43e2c8af20fe64952")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not call create_user, it points to the method create_user.
This is why you get

```
TypeError: self.assertEqual(result["id"], "4") 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Try

```
result = self.post_create_user()
self.assertDictEqual(result,self.data)
# You will face an issue with the line below since response is not defined
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

Not

```
result = self.post_create_user
```

Comment: I have done exactly that but am getting a different error:  RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.  This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.

Comment: @Willie Njati. This is a diffrent topic. If you unit test code starts to work you better close this post and create a new one dealing with the Flask issue you are facing. Add the Flask stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a little bit of further elaboration on the answer already given by @balderman, but here is the reason:

```
result["id"]
```

result is a variable that holds a class method, methods aren't used this way.

when you declare `result = self.post_create_user` python assumes that post_create_user is a property which is not callable with arguments. But since it is a method, you should use self.post_create_user() instead and when you pass it as an argument (without parenthesis) you should supply a second argument as its argument(see balderman's answer above)